# Error on parametrization of a query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, parameters, sql-server-2012

I have a question about the parametrization of a SQL query I created. The original query looks like this:

```
DECLARE @portfolios AS NVARCHAR(MAX)    
DECLARE @Abfrage AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @portfolios = STUFF((SELECT '[' + PortfolioName + '], ' FROM  tblPortfolio ORDER BY PortfolioName FOR XML PATH('')),1,5,NULL)

SELECT @portfolios = LEFT(@portfolios,(LEN(@portfolios)-1))

SET @Abfrage ='
SELECT Description, ' + @portfolios + '
FROM 
( SELECT tblReturnType.Description, tblPortfolio.PortfolioName, tblReturnAbs.Value
FROM 
tblReturnType INNER JOIN ((tblReturnAbs INNER JOIN tblPortfolio ON tblReturnAbs.PortfolioNo = tblPortfolio.PortfolioNo) INNER JOIN tblInstrument ON tblReturnAbs.InstrumentNo =tblInstrument.InstrumentNo) ON (tblReturnType.ReturnType = tblReturnAbs.ReturnType) 
WHERE (tblReturnAbs.Date BETWEEN ''01/01/17'' AND Dateadd("d",-1,''01/31/17'')) AND tblInstrument.Currency = ''EUR'' 
) AS x
PIVOT 
( 
    sum(x.Value)
    For x.PortfolioName in (' + @portfolios + ')
    ) AS piv
ORDER BY Description
'
Execute (@Abfrage)
```

It creates an output where a variable number of portfolios is displayed as columns, with different parts of portfolio earnings displayed under each portfolio name. Now, i would like to use parameters to be able to dynamically change the "WHERE" clause. At the same time, it should be possible to access the query from a frontend (which is yet to be decided). To achieve this, i tried to transform the query in a stored procedure like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Return_Attribution]
    @Startdate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime,
    @Currency nvarchar(10)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @portfolios AS NVARCHAR(MAX)    
    DECLARE @Abfrage AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @portfolios = STUFF((SELECT '[' + PortfolioName + '], ' FROM tblPortfolio ORDER BY PortfolioName FOR XML PATH('')),1,5,NULL)
    SELECT @portfolios = LEFT(@portfolios,(LEN(@portfolios)-1))

    SET @Abfrage ='SELECT Description, ' + @portfolios + '
                  FROM 
                      (SELECT tblReturnType.Description, tblPortfolio.PortfolioName, tblReturnAbs.Value
                       FROM tblReturnType 
                       INNER JOIN ((tblReturnAbs 
                       INNER JOIN tblPortfolio ON tblReturnAbs.PortfolioNo = tblPortfolio.PortfolioNo) 
                       INNER JOIN tblInstrument ON tblReturnAbs.InstrumentNo =tblInstrument.InstrumentNo) ON (tblReturnType.ReturnType = tblReturnAbs.ReturnType) 
                       WHERE (tblReturnAbs.Date >= '+ @Startdate +' AND tblReturnAbs.Date <= Dateadd("d",-1,'+ @EndDate +')) AND tblInstrument.Currency = '+ @Currency +' 
) AS x
PIVOT 
( 
    sum(x.Value)
    For x.PortfolioName in (' + @portfolios + ')
    ) AS piv
ORDER BY Description
'
Execute (@Abfrage)
END
```

Now, if I try to execute this procedure and enter parameters, I get the following error:

> Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Procedure Return_Attribution, Line 16
>   String or binary data would be truncated.

I did a bit of research and I found out that this error normally occurs when a string is too long to fit into a data field. As it only occurs when I used the parametrized procedure, I suppose I made a mistake in either defining or using the parameters. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the content of `@portfolios`? You are concatenating `@portfolios` twice in `@Abfrage`. Both `@Abfrage` and `@portfolios` are declared as NVARCHAR(MAX)

Comment: @portfolios contains a string holding every portfolio name for the PIVOT operator to work.

Comment: yes, but what is the length of the string? Could you try to replace the first select for a fixed and well known value for `@porfolios` or declare it as nvarchar(500) for example?

Comment: The first attempt at debugging this would be to use a `print @Abfrage` or `select @Abfrage` before the execute.

Comment: Also, why the `[` and `]` around the portfolio names in the string? Does it work if you replace the @portfolios with three names and try to run only the pivot-sql before trying to do it dynamically?

Comment: Comment the `execute` and add a `print @Abfrage`, then post the result.

Comment: I think that I got this...since you are concatenating into a nvarchar variable, and your `@Startdate` and `@EndDate` are datetime, then the concatenation fails...

Comment: Replace `+ @Startdate +` with `+ cast(@Startdate as varchar(20)) +`...the same for the other date...

Comment: Thx @Hackerman it worked.
Jonny- thx for your suggestion, I needed to put the portfolio names in brackets because they contain blank spaces and various special characters.

Comment: Glad to help @AlexanderRothländer